# how can we limit gesture in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I have Three type of gestures in my view(tableview is my view)
PinchGesture:redirecting to another page
LeftSwipe:for next chapter
RightSwipe:for previos chapter
Scrolling:tableview scrolling
My requirement is when any one of the gesture acts the other gestures including scrolling of tableview have to be disabled,Is this possible?
my code for gesture is

```
-(void) handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {


     if(![delegate.selectedChapter isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[DbHandler mNumberOfChaptersInBook:delegate.selectedBook]]]) {
        // if the currentChapter is the last then do nothing
         delegate.selectedChapter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[delegate.selectedChapter intValue] + 1];
         [delegate reloadVerses];
         [self resetReadViewToVerse:1];
    }
    return;




}
-(void) handleSwipeGestureleft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

    if(![delegate.selectedChapter isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        delegate.selectedChapter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[delegate.selectedChapter intValue] - 1];
        [delegate reloadVerses];
        [self resetReadViewToVerse:1]; 
    }
    return;


}
-(void) longPressDetected:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {


    SearchViewController *aSecondViewController = [[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController" bundle:nil];
    aSecondViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:aSecondViewController animated:YES];

    /*[self.navigationController pushViewController:aSecondViewController animated:YES];*/

    [aSecondViewController release];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the gesture recognizers don't handle this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your gesture recognizer method is called you can try.

```
if (recognizer.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    //Do your thing.
}
```

HTH.